# How to fix icon align?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple html page but I can't align one of the icons. I don't understand where's the problem with my CSS or HTML.

**Here is the pic of my html page:**

[image: here is the pic of my html page]

```css
.service-icon-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: #FCDB7A;
  font-size: 65px;
}

.service-icon-tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="single-service-icon">
    <div class="service-icon-container">
      <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
        <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt libero, ab repudiandae incidunt dicta eveniet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post all your code for this page?

Comment: [html](https://pastebin.com/JxLca5p5)

[css](https://pastebin.com/SCqz26zx) @B-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, mistakenly, I forgot to add style to `.single-service-icon`. Hence, I just implemented some css to it:

```
.single-service-icon{
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  min-height: 240px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which also can achieve the same UI

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="single-service-icon">
      <div class="service-icon-container">
        <div class="service-icon-tablecell">
          <img src="img/service-icon-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [all html](https://pastebin.com/JxLca5p5)
[all css](https://pastebin.com/SCqz26zx)

can you please check my hole code and fix this?
@Nidhin Joseph

Comment: @Uzzal Did you try it using grid as I did in the solution above?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is in `a.single-service-icon`. Remove `display: block;` and it should align properly.